# Share screen with it's Audio in OpenTok JS SDK

Tags: opentok

I want to publish my Screen with the audio that is inside my computer. That means that I don't want my microphone to publish the audio, but the audio my computer has. Like when I play a video with sound, the subscriber should see the video with the audio.

```
const publish = Promise.all([
  OT.getUserMedia({
    videoSource: 'screen'
  }),
  OT.getUserMedia({
    audioSource: 'screen'
  })
])
.then(([screenStream, soundStream]) => {
  return OT.initPublisher(null, {
    videoSource: screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0],
    audioSource: soundStream.getAudioTracks()[0]
  });
});
```

The above code should work as far as I could tell from their docs, but it is not working. I keep getting the audio from my microphone. Using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in the OpenTok documentation that `audioSource: 'screen'` is supported.

I would try to get access to the screen audio and video tracks with the browser API and then create the OT publisher with those media tracks:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
const publisher = OT.initPublisher(null, {
    videoSource: stream.getVideoTracks()[0],
    audioSource: stream.getAudioTracks()[0]
  });
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture